# Removing opposites from Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I am trying to figure out a way to remove values that have a net result of zero. For example I have data that is `10,000` and `-10,000`. They are linked to the same person though not the only transaction linked to a single individual.

Is there a method to remove both of these rows from my Excel document?

[Here is a the kind of data I'm looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbGbw.jpg)

[image: Here is a the kind of data I'm looking at]

And I want to remove all but the last row as it is the only unique one.

Comment: How is your data laid out? Is it in two columns? Two rows? Also, what if you have `10,000`, `10,000`, and `-10,000` , how do you know which positive one you want to keep?  Can you post some sample data and a sample output of what you expect?

Comment: You can do this using Pivot Tables.

Comment: I have added a small bit of sample data to show what I am kind of looking at.

Comment: So will there *always* be a second matching ID, such as `Cust#` and `Date`?

Comment: Yes, though they sometimes will have another row separating them where there are not 1 after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a helper column with =ABS(A1) copied down and then sort on ColumnB, that helper column and within that on ColumnA - you should end up with sets as you already have pairs. Then in another helper column Row2 and copied down:

```
=IF(OR(A1=-A2,A2=-A3),"#","")
```

should flag 'equal and opposites' next to one another. Remove those and repeat until no more flags appear, if you have multiple instances of equal and opposite values. Beware however where the last value for one `Cust #` is equal and opposite to the first value of the next `Cust #`.